# How can an App Script detect if the onOpen method is called with a Doc, Sheet, or other type of document?

Tags: google-apps-script

In an onOpen method, how can the document type be determined?

From the [Quickstart: Add-on for Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate) the following code is suggested:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi(); 
}
```

However, when a Google Sheet is opened the script throws an exception:

```
Exception: Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context. at onOpen(Code:9:15)
```

There should be a test, first, detecting the document type context that is being opened, allowing the script to select if and how it will add menu items.  How to do that?  The reference for [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers) indicates e.source will be a different type, but `type of e.source` is only `object`.

Desire is something like:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  if (/* answer to this question: test if onOpen called for Doc only */) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
        .addToUi(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- You want to detect the mimeType of Google Docs when the Google Docs is opened. Then, you want to retrieve the object of doc.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Solution:

In this sample script, it retrieves the active document of the container-bound script when the Google Docs is opened. As the sample situation, when this script is used for the container-bound script of Spreadsheet, `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()`, `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()` and `FormApp.getActiveForm()` return `null`. And only `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns the object. This method uses this situation.

#### Sample script:

The sample script is as follows.

```
function onOpen() {
  var docObject = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() ? DocumentApp :
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() ? SpreadsheetApp :
      SlidesApp.getActivePresentation() ? SlidesApp :
      FormApp.getActiveForm() ? FormApp : null;

  // When this is used for your script, it becomes as follows.
  docObject.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
}
```

- For example, when above script is put to Google Document, `docObject` becomes the object of `DocumentApp`. And `docObject.getUi().createAddonMenu().addItem('Start', 'showSidebar').addToUi()` works for the Google Document.

#### Note:

- In this script, the following 4 scopes are used.

  - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents`
  - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms`
  - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations`
  - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`
- For example, if you are not required to check the Google Form, please remove `FormApp.getActiveForm() ? FormApp :`.
- Above script works by the simple trigger. But if you add other methods, it might required to use the installable trigger. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Class DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)
- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app)
- [Class FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

At first, I apologize I misunderstood your goal. From your updated question, I could understand as follows.

- You want to run the script when the parent of the container-bound script is only Google Document.

If my understanding is correct, when the method of my answer is used, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (/* answer to this question: test if onOpen called for Doc only */) {
```

#### To:

```
if (DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()) {
```

- In this case, when this is used to Google Docs except for Google Document, `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` returns `null`. By this, the script in the if statement is not run for Google Docs except for Google Document.

Answer (score 4):

Inbuilt global variable's `.toString()` method usually gives the class name. You can use it to determine the document type.

```
function onOpen(e){
  const app = this[ e.source + "App" ];//automatically becomes SpreadsheetApp or DocumentApp or any other editor App
  app.getUi()/*Do whatever you want with the Ui object*/;
}
```

Comment: Don't expect to work for SlidesApp.  Something like this `this[ (String(e.source) === "Presentation" ? "Slides" : e.source) + "App"]` should work though.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function I wrote for this. The trick is you can't call any methods that access the document scope, otherwise your code will stope executing. So you need to access a function that won't trigger any AuthMode.LIMITED or FULL execution scopes.

```
type Host = 'docs' | 'slides';

function getHost(): Host {
  let appType;

  try {
    var activeDocument = DocumentApp.getUi();
    if (activeDocument) {
      return 'docs';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    // DocumentApp is not available.
    console.info('DocumentApp is not available.')
  }

  try {
    var activePresentation = SlidesApp.getUi();
    if (activePresentation) {
      return 'slides';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    // SlidesApp is not available.
    console.info('SlidesApp is not available.')
  }

  return appType;
}
```

Comment: this is only approach that properly works

Answer (score 0):

The only way it works for me is using try catch operation.

```
function getHost() {
  let docUI;

  try {
    docUI = DocumentApp.getUi();
    if (docUI) {
      return {type:"doc", doc:DocumentApp, docUI};
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log("DocumentApp is not available.");
  }

  try {
    docUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    if (docUI) {
      return {type:"sheet", doc:SpreadsheetApp, docUI};
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log("SpreadsheetApp is not available.");
  }

  return null;
}
   
    
function onOpen(e) {
  const host = getHost();
  if(!host) 
     return;

  Logger.log("onOpen - host " + host.type);
}
```