# Unable to test add-on under 'Installed for current user' config (i.e. AuthMode.NONE)

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on

I'm trying to build my first editor add-on where the same codebase is supposed to work on Docs, Sheets and Slides.

I'm still in the testing phases and that's where I've hit a roadblock. Here's the problem -

As per the documentation for [Installed versus enabled](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled), if one were to select a test config as **Installed for current user** (but not yet enabled it), the Menu **is** supposed to be visible (this would be under `AuthMode.NONE`); however, per my script, its throwing me an error that indicates -

> Google Apps Script: You do not have permission to perform that action.

... and the Menu is not visible either.

*Note: One ought to view this error on the browser console*

Here's the codebase and manifest files -

#### Code.gs

```
var fileUI = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() ? SpreadsheetApp.getUi() : (DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() ? DocumentApp.getUi() : (SlidesApp.getActivePresentation() ? SlidesApp.getUi() : false));

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  if (fileUI) {
    var menu = fileUI.createAddonMenu();
    if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
      menu.addItem('Please Login', 'login');
    } else {
      menu.addItem('Hurray', 'itWorks');
    }
    menu.addToUi();
  }
}

function login() {
  fileUI.alert('Please login to access this add-on');
}

function itWorks() {
  fileUI.alert('Hurray! It works');
}
```

#### appscript.json (Manifest file)

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

### Remarks

- Add-on works perfectly when tested under the other two config criteria (where both have `AuthMode.LIMITED`):

  - Enabled in current document
  - Installed and enabled
- The problem persists across all 3 editors: Docs, Sheets and Slides
- I only require read access for current docs that are being used by the add-on (not sure if I need to edit something there)

I have a feeling that I'm missing something super basic here. I apologize if I've skipped over some part of the documentation that covers this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit note**:

1. Added a 3rd remark on oauthScopes
2. Clarified the problem about menu not being visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a script file is loaded into memory for execution of any function (`onOpen` or any other function), all global variables are loaded/executed. Your issue stems from attempting to get the active(`getActive*()`) document under `AuthMode.None`.

If you can get to `Ui` without getting to `getActive()` that's possible. But you're attempting to access the document inbetween:

> SpreadsheetApp **.getActiveSpreadsheet()** ? SpreadsheetApp.getUi().

The bolded part is causing the issue. `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` will work fine.

You can also try `try{...}...catch(e){}` instead.

#### References:

- [Authorization modes](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes) - Access to document: No under AuthMode: "NONE" table
- [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664706/) - May not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right documentation on this. But, would you happen to know how to make the Menu visible via `AuthMode.NONE`? Referring to [this part](https://imgur.com/snmeDwp) of [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled). Or, am I reading this incorrectly?

Comment: @Sourabh If you can get to `Ui`  without getting to `getActive()` that's possible. But you're attempting to access the document inbetween: `SpreadsheetApp` **`.getActiveSpreadsheet()`** `? SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`. The bolded part is causing the issue. `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` will work fine. I  know what you're attempting to do with accessing the document, you can try `try{...}...catch(e){}` instead if my related  answer in the reference doesn't help.

Comment: Ah! I see what the problem is here. I'm an idiot. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I've been trying the `const app = this[ e.source + "App" ];` from the other answer in all possible combinations (even the 'Presentation' bit) but it still keeps throwing this error - `Google Apps Script: TypeError: Cannot call method "getUi" of undefined.` - I've taken the "App" part outside the brackets and also tried toString() but it all gives the same error. Thoughts?

Comment: Goddam it! Found the easiest way to solve this - `var fileUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() || DocumentApp.getUi() || SlidesApp.getUi() || false;` -- works like a charm :)

Comment: @Sourabh Simply means `e.source` is `undefined`. Basically your question would be the same as the related question: How to determine the type of file in AuthMode.None? As said in my previous comment, you could try `try{..}catch{}`. Try to get sheets ui, catch the error , examine it and try to get docs ui and so on...if that doesn't work, I am out of ideas currently ;) Ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Figured it out (commented above)

Comment: @Sourabh if you read the previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664706/ , your answer won't work in  Google Docs  `However, when a Google Sheet is opened the script throws an exception:Exception: Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context. at onOpen(Code:9:15)` Your answer would work in sheets because it's the first

Comment: I see what I missed here. Need to test further. Let me take some time with this now that I know where I went wrong in the first place.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria did you solve this issue?