# Addon Menu for Google Docs, Google Sheets or Google Slides within the same script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

## Desired situation

Have a clean wrapper function determine current GSuite Application being used (Docs, Sheets or slides in my case) and set the UI accordingly.

## Initial code setup

> Please note that I'm using Babel to transpile the code to ECMAscript2015/AppScript compatible JS code. 
>   My question only relates to the overall logic of what to check against.

```js
export function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = '';
  typeof SpreadsheetApp === 'undefined' ? (ui = DocumentApp.getUi()) : (ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi());

  ui.createMenu('My Addon')
    .addItem('Open SideBar', 'showMySidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function showMySidebar() {
  const ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar').setTitle('My Sidebar');
  let env = '';
  typeof SpreadsheetApp === 'undefined' ? (env = DocumentApp.getUi()) : (env = SpreadsheetApp.getUi());
  env.showSidebar(ui);
}
```

### Result

This works only in Google Sheets. When trying to run the script as an addon in Google Docs I get an error "Cannot execute SpreadsheetApp.getui() from this context".

## Current code setup

```js
export function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = '';
  try {
    ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  } catch (e) {
    ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  }

  ui.createMenu('My Addon')
    .addItem('Open SideBar', 'showMySidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function showMySidebar() {
  const ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar').setTitle('My Sidebar');
  let env = '';
  try {
    env = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  } catch (e) {
    env = DocumentApp.getUi();
  }
  env.showSidebar(ui);
}
```

### Result

This works in both Google Docs and Google Sheets, but not in Google Slides

## Challenge

How can I check against the environment dynamically within Apps Script?

Any thoughts and insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, for example, is this thread useful for resolving your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57651822/7108653

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks, that was helpful. Checking against null with the "activeDocument" seems to be what I need - thanks