# Make Google Apps Script Add-on available to all Google Editor Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, add-on, google-slides

I have written a simple sidebar for Google Slides that makes a REST call and fetches some images. The user can then Copy-Paste some of these images to their document if they wish.
However, my code doesn't depend on or use any Google Slides-specific functionality, and I want to also make it available to Google Docs and Sheets.

Is there any easy way of doing this, without creating a separate app for each Editor program?

I was looking at this [Reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document) hoping to find a parent class to all DocumentApp, SlidesApp and SheetsApp, but couldn't. [Google does define "Utility Services"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) here, which are not supposed to be tied to any specific App, but I cannot use it because my code needs the "SlidesApp" object to create the Sidebar. Is there a way to decouple Sidebar creation from the specific Google Editor app?

```
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars
function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Image Search')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('Image Search');
  SlidesApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Comment: @Kos [tag:google-workspace-add-ons] should not be used for Editor add-ons (use for add-ons that use the Card Service, not for add-ons that use Class Ui)

Comment: @Rubén sorry, I thought editor addons are published as workspace addon too

Comment: I would agree with Kos. Editor add-ons are also published in the "Workspace Marketplace"

Comment: @TheMaster , Kos - Thank you, this seems exactly like what I need! Will try to have a look tonight and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In addition to the solutions provided in the [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651822/how-can-an-app-script-detect-if-the-onopen-method-is-called-with-a-doc-sheet-o/57664706#57664706) mentioned by @TheMaster, you can also implement a simple [try...catch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):**

```js
function onOpen() {
  try{
    SlidesApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Image Search')
    .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();    
  }
  catch(e){
    try{
      DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Image Search')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();   
    }
    catch(e){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Image Search')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
    }
  }
}
```